An inequality about index in finite group
Some denotations
Let G be a finite group.
Let N be a normal subgroup of G.(Which means $\forall n \in N, \forall g \in G, gng^{-1}\in N$)
Let M be an arbitary subgroup of N.
Let H be the normalizer of M in G.(i.e. $H = $ {$g\in G: \forall m\in M, gmg^{-1}\in M$})
For any finite group W, denote the order of W by $|W|$.
Question
Is the following inequality always true?
$ |H|/|M| \geq |G|/|N| $
I found that the inequality is true for some group, including the Dihedral Group $D_4$, the Quaternion Group $Q_8$, the symmetric group $S_4$.
I also found that the inequality is true if $M$ is a Sylow subgroup of $N$. I can provide details if required.
It will be a quite beautiful conclusion if the inequality is true for any group. I will be rather appreciated if anyone may help me with this problem!

Here is counterexample - I don't know whether this is the smallest.
Let $G = {\rm PGL}(2,7)$, $N = {\rm PSL}(2,7)$, $H = S_4$. Then $M:=N_G(H) = H$ so $|H:M|=1$ but $|G:N|=2$.
This situations occurs frequently when looking for maximal subgroups of almost simple groups $G$. The simple socle $N$ of $G$ has classes of maximal subgroups that are permuted in $G$, so they do not extend to maximal subgroups of $G$.
Thinking of $N$ in the above example as ${\rm PSL}(3,2)$, this is the smallest instance of pairs of conjugacy classes of maximal parabolic subgroups of $N={\rm PSL}(n,q)$ for $n \ge 3$ that are interchanged by the inverse-transpose automorphism of $N$.

Thank you for your counter example! But I don't understand why $G=N $ but $ [G:N]=2$? It seems to be a typo

@coiso Yes, thanks, corrected!

Since the counterexample here is an unsolvable group, I wonder whether there's counterexample of solvable group or the inequality is true for any solvable group？

There are solvable examples. I found one of order $108$ with $|N|=36$ and $|M|=12$.
